Can't find storypencil in blender 4.3
I just installed blender 4.3 and I clicked the option to use settings from Blender 4.2, but the problem now is the addon storypencil is not showing under Draw > Storypencil.
I am sure the addon is installed on Preferences > Addons and also active.
But when I uninstall and tried re-installing it i got 'module' object has no attribute 'VIEW3D_MT_draw_gpencil'
Does anyone knows how to fix this, or should I just stick to Blender 4.2 for now until the next update?

It looks as if there's a problem with that addon. See the reviews at the bottom of this page.

Is it possible that the add-on has not been updated to be compatible with the new Blender release?
